# Ubuntu 64 bit 16.04 LTS on laptop Hp Pavilion X2 external HDMI monitor stopped working after latest updates

Tags: hp, hdmi, monitor, hp-pavilion

It seems that Ubuntu is really a problem on HP computers. Now, the new problem is that after the last updates of 16.04, the HDMI port stopped working. I tried with a different monitor and the problem remains. Anyone can give me a clue how to solve this new problem? I already tried to reset bios to defaults and reboot but did not solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: installed windows 10 and the machine did not freeze again.

Comment: Good for you man.